# Vue3: Using v-for with keep-alive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

#### My Problem

I have a variable number of `Tab` components; there can be 1 or 10, but only one is going to be displayed at a time. However, I want to cache them between switches. I thought I could put a `v-for` loop inside a `<keep-alive>` but according to the docs: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/built-in-components.html#keep-alive:

> Note, `<keep-alive>` is designed for the case where it has one direct child component that is being toggled. It does not work if you have `v-for` inside it. When there are multiple conditional children, as above, `<keep-alive>` requires that only one child is rendered at a time.

#### Question

This seems like a pretty standard use-case, so I'm wondering if there's an easier way about this that I'm missing. Is there a best practice to rendering a variable number of components inside the `<keep-alive>` component?

#### Update: Kind of an answer

I was able to separate the Tab logic from the `v-for`, which means the Tabs get generated elsewhere, while the `TabContent` is the only thing inside `<keep-alive>`. Kind of like so:

```html
  <keep-alive>
      <TabContent tab-name="name" />
  </keep-alive>
```

Then internally, TabContent uses the `tab-name` prop to grab the data it needs.

Admittedly it feels like a good solution but I'm open to other ways to solve this.

#### Update 2.0: For Dynamic Components, use `:key`

The last thing I figured out; my `Tab` titles are dependent on filenames, and the TabContent is generated from the file, so it takes a `filename` props. My content was dynamic.

You still can't use a `v-for` inside the `<keep-alive>`, but you *can* use keys still:

```html
  <keep-alive>
    <template>
      <component
        :is="'TabContent'"
        :key="currentTabTitle"
        v-bind="{
          filename: currentTabTitle
        }"
      />
    </template>
  </keep-alive>
```

Comment: Will having one child that itself wraps the `v-for` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Dynamic Components with `keep-alive`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-dynamic-async.html#dynamic-components-with-keep-alive)

```
<div id="dynamic-component-demo" class="demo">
  <button
     v-for="tab in tabs"
     :key="tab"
     :class="['tab-button', { active: currentTab === tab }]"
     @click="currentTab = tab"
   >
    {{ tab }}
  </button>

<!-- Inactive components will be cached! -->
<keep-alive>
  <component :is="currentTabComponent">     </component>
</keep-alive>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats the example they give, but the frustrating part is that they don't offer any examples of how to integrate a `v-for`